# What Design Pattern Have I Ended Up With?

Tags: c#, user-interface, silverlight, design-patterns, xamarin.forms

We have a Silverlight application. It has a couple of pages that sit inside tabs in our UI. In the past, we've called them SavePage, and PanelPage. Save page just has basic functionality for editing the detail of a record, creating new records, and deleting the existing record on screen. PanelPage inherits from SavePage. PanelPage is a little more sophisticated in that panels become visible/invisible based on selections you make on screen.

The code was a huge mess in the Silverlight application. But, recently, I took the step of porting this code to work in Xamarin Forms. I made two failed attempts to do this, and on my third attempt, I got the code to work on all targeted platforms: Silverlight, iOS, Android, and Windows UWP. I'm fairly happy with the class design for now. It could be simpler, but this will do the trick for a while.

The point of this design is that the UI logic is abstracted away from the physical UI controls themselves. I removed the System.Windows usings away from the shared code that sits across both platforms (SavePage, and PanelPage). These pages are more like "Controllers" in the MVC, or MVVC patterns. But, I don't think that what I have created is exactly either of those two patterns. However, I had to split these classes up in to two parts: one for abstract UI calls like SaveAsync(), and one for platform specific UI calls like ReportError. I'm struggling to get the naming of the classes right since I don't even know what design pattern I am using.

Here is a class diagram:
 [image: Class Diagram]
    Here is the code for some of the interfaces concerned:

```
public interface IPage : IRecordSelector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This event should be raised when the busy state of a tab changes
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler<BusyStateChangedEventArgs> BusyStateChanged;
    object PageElement { get; }
}

public interface IButtonDrivenPage : IPage
{
    Task SaveClickAsync();
    Task DuplicateClickAsync();
    Task DeleteClickAsync();
    Task NewClickAsync();
    event EventHandler<ButtonVisibilityChangedEventArgs> ButtonVisibilityChanged;
    IRecord GetRecord();
}

public interface ISavePage : IButtonDrivenPage, IRequestClose
{
    string DataContextXmlSnapshot { get; }
    bool PromptForChangeCancel { get; }
    IRecord SelectedItem { get; }
    Task SetSelectedItemAsync(IRecord selectedItem);
    event EventHandler SelectedItemChanged;
    void Close();
    void SetAutomationObject(object automationObject);
    ISavePageUIController SavePageUIController { get; }
}

public interface ISavePageUIController: IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The UI controller is notifying the page that the UI content has been loaded
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler ContentLoaded;

    /// <summary>
    /// Prompt the user for a yet or a no
    /// </summary>
    Task<bool> GetYesNoFromPrompt(string message, string title);

    /// <summary>
    /// Report an error to the user
    /// </summary>
    void ReportError(string title, string message, Exception exception);

    /// <summary>
    /// Notifies the UI that the DataContext/Binding context has changed
    /// </summary>
    void SetSelectedItem(IRecord selectedItem);

    /// <summary>
    /// The actual UI object that is displayed on screen as the content of the page
    /// </summary>
    object PageElement { get;  }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears residual errors from the screen if they exist
    /// </summary>
    void ClearErrors();

    /// <summary>
    /// The record was saved. The selectedItem parameter will be the saved record from the server.
    /// </summary>
    void CurrentRecordSaved(IRecord selectedItem);

    /// <summary>
    /// This event occurs when the UI wants to notify the controller that a Save button has been clicked in the UI somewhere
    /// </summary>
    event EventHandler SaveClicked;
}


public interface IPanelUIController : ISavePageUIController
{
    void CreateAndAddPanelFromContent(PagePanel pagePanel, double? panelHeight);
    IEnumerable<IPagePanel> GetIPagePanelControls();
    void SetHeader(IPanelHeader pageHeader);
    void SetVisiblePanels(IList<bool> visiblePanels);
    void HideAllPanels();
    event EventHandler<RecordsSelectedRoutedEventArgs> PanelPageRecordsSelected;
}
```

These interfaces have been implemented successfully in Silverlight and Xamarin Forms. So, is this similar to another UI design pattern? Can anyone recommend improvements? Or, tell me what I'd need to do to convert this to a more standard UI design pattern? How about naming? What should I name my classes and interfaces here?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I wouldn't be too obsessed with being one or the other (MVC, MVVM or MVP), they're pretty much the same and the point is to get keep that "big split". That said, right now, IMHO you seem to be closest to MVP (Model View Presenter)

The problem is that you have a lot of intermingled logic there: `IPage` should really just be a `View` but you have it *doing* things that a controller typically would. Same with it's children: `ISavePage`has a method called `SetAutomation` object that I would normally expect to see in a `Controller` (at least if I'm guessing correctly on it's function).

Adam Freeman did a great job talking about how to break this stuff up in ASP.NET MVC 5: http://enos.itcollege.ee/~ijogi/Nooks/Pro%20ASP.NET%20MVC%205/Pro%20ASP.NET%20MVC%205.9781430265290.pdf Check out page 51 where he breaks down what each item should be conceptually, which may help?

I would try doing it this way, given that we've established that your `IPage` is really a Controller.

```
public class PageElement
{
    IPageController _controller;

    // these are your models - your controller will simply allow them to be shown with your other methods
    private PageData _data; 
    private PageData _otherData;

    public PageElement(IPageController ctrl)
    {
         _controller = ctrl;
    }
}

public class PageController : IPageController
{
     IPageService _service;

     public PageController(IPageService service)
     {
          _service = service;
     }

     // this is what your button calls when clicked
     public void SaveAsync(object sender, SomeEventArgs args)
     {
           // the service does the actual work
          _service.SaveAsync()
     }
}

public class PageService : IPageService
{
     public void SaveAsync(){ // what it does}

}
```

Comment: I can see your points here. The problem is that IPage is not really a View. The PageElement  property IS the UI object that the platform will display on screen, but other than that, the IPage interface is really the controller. Historically it was called IPage, but I've been considering renaming it to IPageController.

Comment: It would be a fair point to say that PageElement shouldn't exist on the controller, but the way our system works is that an IPage class is instantiated, and then the PageElement is added in to the Visual Tree.

Comment: I hear you - here's what I would do as an example: assuming that IPage is the controller, I'd simply call it IPageController. It should be restricted to governing the page elements and updating data from a service. That service should be a separate object that DOES the actually work. So you would have a PageElement which contains an IPageController as a member. The IPageController would then have it'd own service (IPageService) so that methods SaveClickAsync are really just calling some method within your service to handle saving and things of that nature.

Comment: That's pretty much how it works. I will rename IPage to IPageController, and instances of IPageController will have instances of a given service client in them. In this case, the service client will be a WCF client. I think what you want me to do is reverse the ownership of objects here. So, the UI (View) itself will own an instance of the controller, rather than the controller owning an instance of the UI. Is that correct? Incidentally, the service client is dependency injected in to the class.

Comment: To a certain extent, yes - if you think about it from that standpoint it frees you up to do a whole bunch of other things too like Dependency Injection etc. That will end up getting you a whole lot closer to a "truer" MV* pattern. I'll update my answer with a little pseudo code too.

Comment: Also, just because I remembered it - in general, I remember a rule (from 'Clean Code' I think) that says that if you're having trouble naming your classes it's because they have too many responsibilities. The author's general thought is that it's better to have a LOT of small classes than one big class

Answer (score 0):

Look like a MVC, or previous controller-view pattern (prior to MVC)